# Java : How to fill a 2d matrix with an array that contains de coordinates?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, initialization

I have an ArrayList : `[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,2,3,0,3,4,0,4,5...]` (the real list has 81 numbers)

I want to find create a matrix with this initialization `int [ ] [ ] project = new int [ 9 ] [ 9 ] ;`

The first number of my ArrayList represent the line, the second number the column and the third number is the number I want to be at that position. And it goes on for all the other numbers of the list, having for an output :

```
project[0][0]= 1 
project[0][1]= 2  
project[0][2]= 3
```

I can't find a way to fill my matrix this way.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting this question?

Comment: Yes, I tried the loop, but as I'm new to Java, I had a ponctuation mistake. But I should have post what I tried in my question. Still learning how to use stackoverflow and java :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see where you are blocking, you can always do:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[9][9];
for (int i = 0, n = list.length(); i < n; i += 3) {
  matrix[list.get(i+0)][list.get(i+1)] = list.get(i+2);
}
```

You would probably first need to check that bounds are valid, but you get the idea.